# Tools or techniques to perform live memory capture of Solaris

Tags: memory

So far I'm hitting a brick wall here. Trying to capture memory from a Solaris 11 machine and nothing seems to work.

- I've tried compiling and using LiME, to no avail
- I've tried `memdump`, gives me garbage output
- Done hours of research, can't find any tools like memoryze, DumpIt, FTKImager, etc... for Unix systems.
- I've tried `dumpadm` (builtin command) with savecore but the files aren't in a format that is recognized by rekall, not even sure what it's producing.
- Tried `dd` of the `/dev/mem` and `/dev/kmem` files. `/dev/kmem` fails, `/dev/mem` only copies about 600M of memory (Out of 4G) and the image isn't recognizable by rekall.

Looking for a tool or procedure that will allow me to create a .img or .raw file of the memory.

I'm not asking anyone to do this for me, but a point in the right direction would be amazing.

Comment: @techraf thank you for the edit. I was at the end of an already extremely frayed rope, been working at this for three days now. I appreciate the proper formatting and markup.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Linux kernel programs won’t work with Solaris.

You will need to follow the procedure that Sun specifies for dumping a live system, and use their tool (mdb) for analysing.  Note that dumping a live system requires configuring the dedicated service to support it.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1451/tscrashdumps-4.html#tscrashdumps-32